# Image stitching / texture blending in OpenGL (or OpenGL ES)

Tags: image-processing, opengl, alphablending, blending, image-stitching

I've got two YUV images (YUV 420 SP), which have been loaded in fragment shader as textures.

These textures are having an overlapping area.

Now, I am trying to blend these two textures such that there should **not** be any difference visible in the brightness over the overlapping area. (Basically stitching the images)

[[image]]

- Can you suggest any method on how I can mix/blend/stitch these two images.
- I have come across the concept of Alpha Masking in OpenCV. I am not sure how it is applicable in OpenGL. Also, since I am using YUV images, which are loaded as textures, as R and RG component (for Y and UV), and further converting it to RGB Color space in the fragment shader.

***Note***: I am not considering any geometrical alignment for now. I know after the blending/stitching the image will not quite good looking as the images are not oriented or placed properly. My question is only regarding the photometric/color alignment on how I can handle the overlapping area.

Comment: When stitching images with OpenCV, so-called MultiBandBlender is used (https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d5/d4b/classcv_1_1detail_1_1MultiBandBlender.html). Method is described in this paper: http://persci.mit.edu/pub_pdfs/spline83.pdf . You can try `stiching_detailed.cpp` example, referenced here: https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html . Though I do not know how to implement that in OpenGL GLSL, but that would  be very usful, as CPU blending is rather slow...